# Trying to add one number to an x-axis scale in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I can't understand why I can make the x-axis scale shorter, to make it end at 5 by removing number 6 in `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)`, but if I add number 7 at the end of the line of numbers to make the scale end at 7, nothing happens. What's the matter?

The code

```
bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, .id = 'id') %>%
  filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q10")) %>% 
  mutate(id = factor(id,levels = c("df1","df2")),question=factor(question,levels=c("Q3","Q2","Q1", "Q10"))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(mean, question, fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) +
  ylab("question") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("df1"="red","df2"="green"),labels=c("df1","df2"))
```

The data frames

```
df1 <- structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), n = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), mean = c(5.38461538461539, 
4.38461538461539, 4.69230769230769, 4.30769230769231, 5.15384615384615, 
5.38461538461539, 4.76923076923077, 5.30769230769231, 4.53846153846154, 
5.61538461538461, 5.69230769230769, 4.92307692307692), sd = c(1.26085034391223, 
1.44559454541846, 1.03155347127648, 1.60128153805087, 0.898717034272917, 
1.12089707663561, 1.01273936708367, 0.85485041426511, 0.967417922046845, 
1.26085034391223, 0.85485041426511, 1.84668795692624)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), n = c(204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L), 
    mean = c(5.22549019607843, 4.87684729064039, 4.95098039215686, 
    4.39705882352941, 5.47058823529412, 5.51470588235294, 4.50490196078431, 
    4.92647058823529, 4.40686274509804, 5.56862745098039, 5.56372549019608, 
    5.23529411764706), sd = c(1.1524816893289, 1.21443704569259, 
    1.31214449357814, 1.5422430010719, 1.12039650223724, 1.15104553532809, 
    1.37714471881058, 1.34621721218454, 1.30030385262334, 0.871099231072865, 
    0.830963499839951, 1.36945187401243)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that with `breaks` you set the breaks of the axis. However, only breaks which fit inside the `limits` of the scale will actually show up. By default the limits are set according to the range of the data. Hence, if you want to have breaks outside of the range of your data you have to adjust the `limits`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, .id = "id") %>%
  filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q10")) %>%
  mutate(id = factor(id, levels = c("df1", "df2")), question = factor(question, levels = c("Q3", "Q2", "Q1", "Q10"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(mean, question, fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), limits = c(0, 7)) +
  ylab("question") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("df1" = "red", "df2" = "green"), labels = c("df1", "df2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much stefan